# Property injection and setting properties on the injected type

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, tdd, inversion-of-control

If one uses property injection how do you set properties on that type? For example

```
public class MyClass
{
   public ITimer MyTimer {get;set;}
}
```

We can use DI to resolve ITimer but how/where do we define property values for ITimer, for example, if you want to set the Interval property where does this happen?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you are missing a property name. Also, is this the `ITimer` interface in the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server namespace? If so, I don't recall an `Interval` property for ITimer.

Comment: No its a wrapper so I can unit test Timers and Timer is my property name. Updated question to make property name more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clarify ...what do you mean by *'if you want to set the Interval property where does this happen?'* If you are looking for when to set properties for ITimer, I prefer using a method for better readability and maintenance:

```
public class MyClass {
    private ITimer timer;

    public ITimer Timer {
        get { return timer; }
        set { SetDefaultTimer(value); }
    }

    private void SetDefaultTimer(ITimer timer) {
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        // other default properties

        // assign
        this.timer = timer;
    }
}
```

I don't believe this will stop someone from altering the interval or other properties on the Timer. I don't know if that is your intent.

**Update:**
Depending on your ITimer interface, you could completely hide the Interval property which means that the interval could not be altered because of encapsulation. Exposing the interval property through encapsulation requires something like the following:

```
public interface ITimer {
    int Interval {get; set;}
}
```

...exposes a way to set an interval value - e.g.:

```
public class MyTimer : ITimer {
    Timer timer;

    // implement ITimer member
    public int Interval {
        get { return timer.Interval; }
        set { timer.Interval = value; }
    }
}
```

If the interface did not define the property, there is no way to access the encapsulated timer properties outside of your controlled API (except maybe by reflection ...)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you know that you want specific settings for an `ITimer` that gets injected into `MyClass`, you can do that work in the setter of the `Timer` property.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private ITimer _timer;

    public ITimer Timer
    {
        get { return _timer; }
        set 
        {
            if(_timer = null && value != null && value.Interval == 0)
            {
                value.Interval = 5000;
            }

            _timer = value;
        }
}
```

Really, constructor injection gives you a lot more flexibility for this sort of thing.

Comment: ITimer is an optional dependency

Comment: @Jon You can always inject `null` or a `NullTimer` implementation of `ITimer` that does nothing.

Comment: Looks a bit messy then don't you think?

Comment: @Jon What looks messy? Injecting dependencies in the constructor?

Comment: @Jon Yeah, I wouldn't advocate that -- I'd use a `NullTimer`, as long as that fits with what you're doing.

Comment: Injecting null or a null-object has nothing to do with whether out not you use ctor or property injection. In both cases you'll deal with the potential of not getting an object.

Comment: @AssafStone True, but in the case of the constructor you can treat `null` as an exception; not necessarily so in a property setter. The point is that Jon has indicated that the dependency is "optional." I'm suggesting that you can still use constructor injection.

Comment: I agree. I personally prefer to use null-objects, and to inject by constructor. The only time I'll use property injection is if I can change the dependency during the life of my object, i.e. it isn't immutable.